# Re size of header on change of window size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is my code which is working fine when the window is in full size. But on window re size, the logo and the header does not appear properly.[Here is my code](https://jsfiddle.net/c7germbj/)
Do I need to change the CSS or can the same using bootstrap. I tried changing the values given in pixel to percentag. Still it didn't work.

```
<div class='header'>
    <img style='position:absolute;margin: 12px 10px;'  src='https://business.microsoft.com/-/media/mssc/footericons/xbox.ashx?h=52&la=en&w=52&hash=94B5BB82970A4CF66DBE9F0D78B7E10EBD2D9A5B'/>
    <h1 class="heading">My page</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to place all your CSS code in a separate file.

It's possible to put the image inside the H1 tag, it can be OK with a logo. you would start with this:

```
.heading {
  display: inline; 
}
```

But, If you just want to make the content structured and make it stay together... add a minimum width, like this:

```
.navContent{ 
min-width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below responsive css so that it will allow you to resize your window till width 992px. for this use below code to make it responsive

```
/* responsive css start */
@media (min-width:992px){
.heading{ text-align: center;}
.navContent{text-align: left;float: left; padding-left:0px; padding-right: 15px; position: relative;}   
/* responsive css end */
```

I am attaching screenshot for your reference in which you can see it will does not overlap your header content. But its max width limit is restricted to 992px. you can change it as per your requirement.[image]